# Generic class with an interface constraint vs class implementing interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Recently I was implementing a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure and decided the Nodes could store different types of data or have its implementation varied so then I went for `Node<T>`. Then as I got into the algorithm for constructing the Trie I realised it required more intimate knowledge of the Node so I constrained the generic class to use an `INode` interface. This allows for more flexibility but felt wrong in the context of a generic class.

Generic classes have a different use case to classes which implement an interface. For example, `List<T>` - the algorithm can work without being dependent on a related set of abstractions. A class which implements an interface may require polymorphism/DI but the interfaces will be more specialized.

Under what circumstances do others apply a generic class T where T may implement a more specialized interface?

I thought that a generic class is used when T does not really need to expose operations/data though I can see a generic class may be used where T implements IDisposable or some other more general interface.

Any help in clarifying these points?

Comment: Before generalising the question, could you expand on "I realised it required more intimate knowledge of the Node so I constrained the generic class to use an INode interface"? What did you put on the interface that couldn't have been on the generic class?

Comment: "Under what circumstances do others apply a generic class T where T may implement a more specialized interface? "  - under exactly these: when a generic class can not be "generic enough" to handle all types (because it doesn't make sense, or whatever other reason), but just some of them. Nothing strange about that.

Comment: @AakashM Specific methods/properties required on the Node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with placing constraints on the generic argument. Having a generic argument does not imply "this will work for anything", it implies that there is more than one way that the code will make sense.

It might actually expose a completely generic concept, like `List<T>`, but it might expose a concept that makes sense only in some contexts (like `Nullable<T>` only making sense for non-nullable entities)

The constraints are just that mechanism that you use to tell the world under what circumstances the class will make sense, and will enable you to actually use that (constrained) argument in a reasonable way, i.e. calling `Dispose` on things that implement `IDisposable`

The extreme of this is when the context is very constrained, i.e. what if there are only two possible implementations? I actually have that case in my current codebase, and I use generics. I need some processing done on some data point, and currently (and in the foreseeable future) there are only two kinds of data points. This is, in principle, the code I use:

```
interface IDataPoint 
{ 
   SomeResultType Process();
}

class FirstKindDataPoint : IDataPoint 
{
   SomeResultType Process(){...}
};

class SecondKindDataPoint : IDataPoint 
{
   SomeResultType Process(){...}
};

class DataPointProcessor<T> where T: IDataPoint
{
   void AcquireAndProcessDataPoints(){...}
}
```

It makes sense, even in this constrained context, because I have only one processor, so only one logic to take care of, instead of two separate processor that I will have to try to keep in sync.

This way I can have a `List<T>` and an `Action<T>` within the processor instead of a `List<IDataPoint>` and `Action<IDataPoint>` which will be incorrect in my scenario, as I need a processor for a more specific data type, that is still, implementing `IDataPoint`.

If I needed a processor that will process anything, as long as it is an `IDataPoint`, it might make sense to remove the its genericity, and simply use `IDataPoint` within the code.

Additionally, the point raised in @dasblinkenlight's answer is very valid. If the generic parameters can be both structs and classes than using generics will avoid any boxing.

Comment: The logical extension of your answer then is that a generic class might not be generic at all as T could be some very specific interface?

Comment: If there is more than one possible value for T (even if it's two), then, according to me, being generic will make sense. (I'll elaborate in the answer)

Comment: +1 *Having a generic argument does not imply "this will work for anything", it implies that there is more than one way that the code will make sense.*

Comment: @inquisitive I accept that but was trying to understand when to choose one thing over the other or if it was just difference in syntax/style

Comment: @Jaycee, dont choose one over the other. they are two instruments at your disposal. go for the best mix.

Comment: @SWeko Thanks good, but why decide to use a generic DataPointProcessor and not just a class that holds a reference to an IDataPoint. This is the nub of the question?

Comment: @inquisitive Sure but there are considerations in which way to go - so far I have boxing/unboxing with value types, using the actual type outside the class rather than just the interface...which makes me choose one over another

Answer (score 5):

When faced with a choice to use a generic with an interface constraint vs. a non-generic with an interface type, I would go for generic+interface only in situations when some or all of types passed as generic arguments are value types. This would prevent my implementation from requiring costly boxing and unboxing when dealing with my `struct`s.

For example, if the interface happens to be `IComparable`, I wold definitely prefer a generic with a constraint, because it would let me avoid boxing when working with primitives.

Note that an alternative way of providing functionality to your generic class is passing a delegate along with the value. For example, if you plan to do something like this

```
interface IScoreable {
    decimal GetScore(object context);
}
class Node<T> where T : IScoreable {
    ...
    void DoSomething(T data) {
        var score = data.GetScore(someContext);
        ...
    }
}
```

you can also do this:

```
class Node<T> {
    private Func<T,object,decimal> scorer;
    public Node(Func<T,object,decimal> scorer) {
        this.scorer = scorer;
    }
    ...
    void DoSomething(T data) {
        var score = scorer(data, someContext);
        ...
    }
}
```

The second solution lets you "decouple" the scoring functionality from the type being scored, at the expense of having the caller to write a little more code.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are usually used where using an interface or a base class (and this includes `object`) are not enough, for example where you are worried about the return value's of your function being the original type rather than just the interface, or where the parameters you are passing in may be expressions that operate on the specific type.

So if you approach the logic from the other end. The decisions on type restrictions should be the same decision as when you are choosing the types of your function parameters.

Comment: Interesting, so the decision would come down to how the class is used, so as to avoid casting from an interface to a more specific type.

Comment: @Jaycee Yes and it also provides compile time type checking rather than runtime which could throw an exception.